# remove similar lines in text file

Tags: python

I am not using Python but I have script in python:

part of script

```
elif line.find("CONECT") > -1:
                con = line.split()
                line_value = line_value + 1
                #print line_value
                #print con[2]
                try:
                        line_j = "e" + ', ' + str(line_value) + ', ' + con[2] + "\n"
                        output_file.write(line_j)
                        print(line_j)
                        line_i = "e" + ', ' + str(line_value) + ', ' + con[3] + "\n"
                        output_file.write(line_i)
                        print(line_i)
                        line_k = "e"+ ', ' + str(line_value) + ', ' + con[4] + "\n"
                        print(line_k)
                        output_file.write(line_k)
                except IndexError:
                        continue
```

which give .txt output in format

```
e, 1, 2

e, 1, 3

e, 1, 4

e, 2, 1

e, 2, 3

etc.
```

I need remove similar lines with the same numbers, but no matter on order this numbers

i.e. line e, 2, 1..

Is it possible?

Comment: You said your metric for "similarity" is whether the lines have the same numbers. Does the count of the numbers make a difference?

Comment: Yes, e is element which join point 1 with point 2 then joint point 1 with point 3 etc, but next again joint point 2 with point 1 and this is problem. I have two same lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it is better to modify your code to remove that lines BEFORE you're writing them to file. You can use a list to store already saved values, and on each itereation, perfom a search if the values you're want to add is already exists in that list. The code below isn't tested and optimized, but it explains an idea:

```
# 'added = []' should be placed somewhere before 'if'
added = []     

# you part of code
    elif line.find("CONECT") > -1:
                    con = line.split()
                    line_value = line_value + 1
                    try:
                            line_j = "e, %s, %s\n" % (str(line_value),con[2])
                            tmp = sorted((str(line_value),con[2]))
                            if tmp not in added:
                                added.append(tmp)
                                output_file.write(line_j)
                                print(line_j)
                            line_i = "e, %s, %s\n" % (str(line_value),con[3])
                            tmp = sorted((str(line_value),con[3]))
                            if tmp not in added:
                                added.append(tmp)
                                output_file.write(line_i)
                                print(line_i)
                            line_k = "e, %s, %s\n" % (str(line_value),con[4])
                            tmp = sorted((str(line_value),con[4]))
                            if tmp not in added:
                                added.append(tmp)
                                print(line_k)
                                output_file.write(line_k)
                    except IndexError:
                            continue
```

Comment: not working : must use keyword argument for key function, what does it mean?

Comment: please show a full traceback and what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison method for two lines of your file:

```
def compare(line1, line2):
    els1 = line1.strip().split(', ')
    els2 = line2.strip().split(', ')
    return Counter(els1) == Counter(els2)
```

See [the documentation for the `Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

If the count of elements doesn't matter you can replace the `Counter` class with `set` instead

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should work. First add the following line further up in your code:

```
seen = set()
```

Then replace everything inside the `try` with the following code:

```
for con_value in con[2:5]:
    entry = frozenset((line_value, con_value))

    if entry not in seen:
        seen.append(entry)
        line_j = "e" + ', ' + str(line_value) + ', ' + con_value + "\n"
        output_file.write(line_j)
        print(line_j)
```

Make sure this code is indented to the same level as the code it replaces.